# jquery: .attr() fails for child element

Tags: jquery, jquery-attributes

I'm going crazy staring at this. I need to change the attribute of an element, something which I have done many times before. But it fails. Now I can't even get jquery to show me the attribute that it has. Does it have to do with what is returned by find()?

```
var c = new_photo_div.find('[class = photo]')[0];
alert(c);
alert(new_photo_div.attr('class'));
alert(c.attr('class'));
```

The first alert correctly identifies the element: Object HTMLImageElement

The second alert correctly gives me the class of new_photo_div.

The third alert fails. No alert.

I think it should say: photo

Comment: Have a look at the console for the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `new_photo_div.find('[class = photo]')[0]` Dom element not jquery object .
try this

```
$(c).attr('class');
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because `c` is not a jQuery object. Remove `[0]` to assign a jQuery object to `c`.

Answer (score 0):

In your browser console, an error would have come,

anyway, attr is a method of jQuery, dont do a [0],

Also you can use .prop instead of .attr if you are using a newer jquery library.